# How to define get_queryset, get_context_data in a django view?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I want show a tree with `Authors` and `Books` written for each Author in sub item,
like [show in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrqZQ.jpg) and... I have two models `Author` and `Book` in a OneToMany relationship.

```
#models.py
from django.db import models

class Author(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length = 250)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Name

class Book(models.Model):
    Title = models.CharField(max_length = 250)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Title


#views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, ListView

from .models import InstanciaJudicial, SedeJudicial

class Prueba(ListView):
    model = SedeJudicial
    template_name = 'instancias/pruebas.html'
```

I know that I defined `get_queryset` and `get_context_data`, but I don't know how I did this.

Comment: where's the relationship between the models?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all you need to establish a `ForeignKey` relationship between your models.

```
#models.py
from django.db import models

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, related_name="books")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Title
```

Now in your view you should be able to retrieve your list of authors by overriding the `get_queryset` method like this:

```
#views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, ListView

from .models import Author

class BooksByAuthorList(ListView):
    model = Book
    template_name = 'instancias/pruebas.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Author.objects.prefetch_related("books").all()
```

With just the above view you should be able to have in your template:

```
<ul>
{% for author in object_list %}
  <li>{{author.name}}</li><ul>
  {% for book in author.books.all %}
    <li>book.title</li>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Now say you want to customize that so that instead of the generic `object_list` the context variable was instead something sensible in the domain like `authors`.

Just augment your view like this:

```
class BooksByAuthorList(ListView):
    model = Author
    template_name = 'instancias/pruebas.html'
    context_object_name = 'authors'        

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Author.objects.prefetch_related("books").all()
```

Note you don't need `get_context_data` at all yet.

Assuming you'd like to include some additional data you'll just want to override `get_context_data` and in this case you'll want to keep the object list that's already in your context by calling the superclasses `get_context_data` method first.

Just do:

```
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super(BooksByAuthorList, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        # add whatever to your context:
        context['whatever'] = "MORE STUFF"
        return context
```

`get_context_data` arguments are determined by your routes.  `*args` and `**kwargs` should probably be replaced with something specific to your view and route in your actual code.

Comment: @stderrt, thanks for your patience and your time, I, try this code, but in template, I, modified the line with book.title to {{ book.title }},  and I, get following error: 'RelatedManager' object is not iterable,

Comment: I, solved adding .all to second for: {% for book in author.books.all %}
    <li>book.title</li>
  {% endfor %}